# Django URL regex between various exact string matches

Tags: python, django, regex

Django (v2.2)

I'm trying to achieve a route which consists of three exact matches `all`, `gs` and `webservice` to do a filter in a table on the page.

```py
path(r'^(?P<mode>all|gs|webservice)$', get_orders, name='dash.orders_mode'),
```

```
path('(?P<mode>/^all$|^gs$|^webservice)/$', get_orders, name='dash.orders_mode'),
```

both ways don't seem to work

It's because there are ids on the route aswell.

**EDIT:**

This was the solution to the problem (without having `NoReverseMatch at /dash/orders/all`):

```
re_path('(?P<mode>(all|gds|ws))', get_orders, name='dash.orders_mode'),
```

Comment: You use `path`, not `re_path`

Answer (score 3):

In order to use *regexes*, you should use [**`re_path(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#re-path), [**`path(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#path) is a function that uses *path converters*:

```
    re_path(r'^(?P<mode>all|gs|webservice)$', get_orders, name='dash.orders_mode'),
```

That being said, it might be better to here simply make three paths, and perhaps use the `kwargs=…` parameter to pass extra data to the view. That way you make it more readable what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid putting business logic into your urls.

```
path('<mode>', get_orders, name='dash.orders_mode'),
```

Then in your views

```
from django.http import Http404
def get_orders(request, mode):
    if mode not in ['all', 'gs', 'webservice']:
        raise Http404
```